# Best way of concatenate String in java

Tags: java

What is the best way to concatenate two Strings in java. likely best performance and less memory usage. Please help me..!

Comment: The best way is not asking this question here and make a minimal research.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I would've suggested `string1 += string2` but I can't guarantee that it has the best performance and least memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(firstString);
stringBuilder.append(secondString);
String string = stringBuilder.toString();
```

But according to @a_horse_with_no_name the following is even more efficient

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(firstString.length() + secondString.length()); 
sb.append(firstString); 
sb.append(secondString);
String string = sb.toString();
```

Comment: `new StringBuilder(firstString.length() + secondString.length()); sb.append(firstString); sb.append(secondString);` should be more efficient